# How to display scrollbar in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scrollbar

I want to display some kind of indication to guide user to scroll.

Usually when we touch the UITableView scrollbar appears if needed. But I want this scrollbar indication already displayed on my tableview.

How is it possible to do so?

Comment: late too but: I wrote a possibility at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412629/how-to-always-visible-scroller-of-tableview-in-obj-c/5002298#5002298

Answer (score 37):

If you have a table view that goes offscreen, you can call

`[self.tableView flashScrollIndicators];`

and they will flash to show the user that they are there. This is usually put in viewDidAppear.

(If you inherit from UITableViewController then you will have a self.tableView instance variable, if not then substitute another UITableView.)

If you a scroll view's entire contents fit within its view then no scroll bars are displayed; to test this display a table view with only one cell. If the content size is larger than the view's frame then scroll bars will be displayed; only then will `[self.tableView flashScrollIndicators];` actually flash scroll indicators.

Comment: This only flashes it, as said by Mike below it shows when the user scrolls but otherwise is hidden.

Answer (score 12):

There's no way to force the scrollbar to appear, short of messing with the internals of UITableView(which you shouldn't do), or redesigning your own table view class.

Per the documentation of UIScrollView's [showsVerticalScrollIndicator](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/showsVerticalScrollIndicator) property: "The indicator is visible while tracking is underway and fades out after tracking."