# How to always visible scroller of Tableview in Obj c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to show user there is a more content below but UITableView only shows scroll indicator when we scroll the tableview. There is any way, so I can show scroll indicator always

Comment: Did You solve this problem?

Comment: hi @mahek i am wondering this problems , Did you solve it.? please give me some suggestion . Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.8 target:self selector:@selector(indicator:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
       [timer invalidate];
}

-(void)indicator:(BOOL)animated{
      [tableViewer flashScrollIndicators];
    NSLog(@"asda");
}
```

Just blink the scrollbar

Comment: This chunk of code works better but problem with iPad Air and app images not loaded after implemnt the above code So any clue about that problem

Answer (score 3):

There's no way (that I know of) to permanently display the scrollbars. You can

```
[tableView flashScrollIndicators]
```

in `-viewDidAppear:` to shortly display the scrollbars when the view is shown.

Also, if you have many entries, you might wanna consider showing the (alphabetic) section index at the right. To do that, define `-sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` in your `UITableViewDataSource`. Using `tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount` you can define the minimum number of entries to display the section Index.

Answer (score 3):

I did it:) I'm programming in MonoDevelop, so I only describe the method:

You have to make your own `UITableView` class.
There you overload `PerformSelector` and do NOT call the base function of it,
but call `flashScrollIndicators` if the name of the Selector is **`_notifyPopOverStoppedScrolling`**.

Overload function `ReloadData` and there call `flashScrollIndicators` as well. Only at zooming it will disappear, but you can call `flashScrollIndicators` at zooming too.

Comment: You lose functionality. While works, there should be a better way.

Comment: @Ilesh i did only edited for better viewing not posted that. you have to ask Gerold ;)

Comment: @Neysor Thanks for reply . and i got solution for this question . :)

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```

This may help you in solving your problem

Answer (score 2):

I got Solution for this question .

 Implement UIImageView

```
@implementation UIImageView (UIScrollView)
    - (void) setAlpha:(float)alpha {

        if (self.superview.tag == noDisableVerticalScrollTag) {
            if (alpha == 0 && self.autoresizingMask == UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin) {
                if (self.frame.size.width <10 && self.frame.size.height > self.frame.size.width) {
                    UIScrollView *sc = (UIScrollView*)self.superview;
                    if (sc.frame.size.height < sc.contentSize.height) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (self.superview.tag == noDisableHorizontalScrollTag) {
            if (alpha == 0 && self.autoresizingMask == UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin) {
                if (self.frame.size.height <10 && self.frame.size.height < self.frame.size.width) {
                    UIScrollView *sc = (UIScrollView*)self.superview;
                    if (sc.frame.size.width < sc.contentSize.width) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [super setAlpha:alpha];
    }
    @end
```

And Set tag Tableview or Scrollview Like

```
#define noDisableVerticalScrollTag 97240626 //for visible only vertical scrollIndicator.
#define noDisableHorizontalScrollTag 9898460 // for visible only Horizontal scrolling.
```

and for Tableview `[tableView flashScrollIndicators];` and scrollview `[[scrollobj flashScrollIndicators]];` Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the piece of code works for me, add this code in viewDidAppear

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
      self.tableView_service.flashScrollIndicators()
    }
```

Happy Coding !!!