# tableViewer flashScrollIndicators not showing scrollers in UItableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I had an application where i want to show **scrollers** all the time in `UItableview`,I am hiding and showing this `tableview` according to conditions,I am using this line of code to show the **scrollers** in all the time in `UItableview`,in viewdidappear ,but i am hiding and showing this table on so many places.

```
 [self.tableview performSelector:@selector(flashScrollIndicators) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Can anybody guide me to find where i am going wrong?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625683/show-scrollbar-in-uitableview-before-the-table-is-dragged-down-in-a-way-the-ui

Comment: Where have you written this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to always visible scroller of Tableview in Obj c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412629/how-to-always-visible-scroller-of-tableview-in-obj-c)

Comment: @Mrunal in viewdidappear

Comment: As there is less codebase provided by you, I am not sure. But I guess where you are setting the hidden property for tableview over there only you require to write that `performSelector` line. So it makes first, show the tableview and in few seconds delay it should flash scoll-bars. You can use 2/3 seconds delay as per your project requirements