# How to make a list view in IOS with Scroll

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I need to make a view as below. (Any starters on this would be helpful.)

[image]

1) I need to add a list of items into a view.

2) The particular item should be highlighted if I touch the item in the list and need to get the value of that item.

3) The list should be in scrolled view if extended.

Any starters on this would be helpful.

Comment: better use UITableView

Comment: Have a look at this github link and try to run [github link](https://github.com/ayushcshah/CustomUITableViewCell) and if you want to highlight on tap have a look at this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265662/how-to-change-color-of-uitableviewcell-when-selecting/16266004#16266004 and to show scroll bar on UITableView have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/1978526/1959180 and you can also follow this Simple [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `UITableView` rather then create custom `UIView`.
All the Functionality that you need, are available in `UITableView`.

> For your information, you need to use **UITableViewStyleGrouped**.

Read This [official documentation of UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/)

There are may tutorial available but may be it is better for beginner

[tutorial - 1.](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/)

[tutorial - 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/uitableview)

Also if you are interesting with [custom UITableView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UITableView) Then it is the best site forever.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`UITableViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). These classes provide the functionality you need.

To get you started, read Apple's [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1). It explains the use of table views in great detail.